# Relationship between d group and $\Delta_O$ value found in Tanabe-Sugano diagram

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-field-theory

So this question came up in class recently and got me thinking, is there any relationship between the metal d group and the $\Delta_O$ found for some allowed transition in Tanabe-Sugano diagram?
I mean, for a $d^3$ complex the value found for $\Delta_O$ is the same of the highest energy transition, is that the same for all other $d^n$? And of not, is there any other relationship between $\Delta_O$ and the highest energy transition?

Comment: The site expects that you write explicit compact summary of your prior effort to answer the question, based on your knowledge and on searching for existing related  info or answers.